# Database of EEG signal phenomenon

Tags: eeg, brain-computer-interface

I'm working on a paper describing the current state of EEG headsets used as computer interfaces. One of the things that is key for building a system using an EEG headset as a controller is having some known EEG response to detect. Examples I've been learning about are the P300, the SSVEP, motor-image-related changes in mu & beta rhythm amplitudes, and slow cortical potentials.

Has anyone created a common database or textbook of known phenomenon like these? I'm not talking about implementations that detect and use the signal changes, but rather a comprehensive list of everything currently known about EEG data. Everything that can be reliably reproduced, regardless of whether the underlying brain function is understood.

Answer (score 3):

If you have learned about the P300, Steven Luck's An introduction to the event-related potential technique (2014) will be of interest; 
the SSVEP and motor-image-related changes are used in BCI, so this book "Brain-Computer Interfaces: Principles and Practice" by John and Elizabeth Wolpaw will be helpful.